# Export Excel calculator to php?

Tags: php, html, excel

I have a financial calculator in MS excel, and I basically want to display it on my website. It's not a big database file or anything, it is a simple user interactive savings calculator. I know about the fgetcsv() function where I can import a csv file using php, but my excel file contains formulas and cell associations. 
How could I import the excel calculator into php and display it on a webpage?

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at any of the PHP libraries that can read Excel files?

Comment: Have any of your nine previous questions been answered to your satisfaction? We may be able to provide better answers if we have a sense of the type of information that works for you.

Comment: Yes I have, but I couldn't find anything unique to my situation. I tried several out but it did not work. That is exactly why I came here, in the hope that someone might know how or have done it before. I can't see why this question got marked down and what it has to do with my previous questions. You can either help me or you can't, and many other people can also find help in the answers provided here. Thank you for your answers. I'm one step closer now

Comment: You won't find anything that exactly matches your situation, but you might find libraries that can help you.... but unless you tell us what you've tried, you're asking us to list every option whether you've already seen and discarded it or not.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm not an expert at php, just need a push in the right direction. That's how you learn right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net), especially the Quadratic equation solvers in the /Tests directory... that will show you an example of how this can be done.

It isn't a mortgage calculator, but a form that accepts inputs from a user, uses those values to populate cells in a spreadsheet, accesses formulae defined in that spreadsheet, and displays the results of those calculations.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did not know at which file/s to look between all those files. This certainly narrows it down. Thanks